# Toggle Switch classes -- unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a toggle switch, which I am trying to add/remove classes from each button through Javascript. The code for the buttons is:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".upload-video">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".upload-video">No</button>
</div>
```

I can get my Javascript to amend the buttons for the first time you click them, by cycling classes on and off in a particular order so as there are never two buttons with the `btn-default` class at the same time:

```
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
        $(this).find('.btn-success').removeClass('btn-default');
        $(this).find('.btn-danger').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).find('.btn-default').removeClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).find('.btn-success').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size()>0) {

    }

});
```

However when I try and run the code "in reverse", toggling the switch back the other way, I get seriously unexpected behaviour. Take a look in Chrome's Console and watch the classes react wildly:

```
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
        $(this).find('.btn-success').removeClass('btn-default');
        $(this).find('.btn-danger').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).find('.btn-default').removeClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).find('.btn-success').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size()>0) {
        $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.btn-default').addClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).find('.btn-danger').removeClass('btn-default');
        $(this).find('.btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).find('.btn-default').removeClass('btn-success');
        $(this).find('.btn-danger').addClass('active');
    }

});
```

[I have created a jsFiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewpeckham/gP562/1/). Is there an easier way to do this? Why am I getting the results that I do? Is Bootstrap's `collapse` plugin somehow interfering?

Comment: the second if block should be an `else if` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted, in javascript if you have multiple if's you need to do an else if.

http://jsfiddle.net/6s9Ab/

```
    else if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size() > 0) {
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.btn-toggle').children().click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $a = $(this);
        $b = $(this).parent().find('.active');
        if($b.hasClass('btn-danger')) {
            $a.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success').addClass('active');
            $b.removeClass('btn-danger').removeClass('active').addClass('btn-default');
        } else {
            $a.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-danger').addClass('active');
            $b.removeClass('btn-success').removeClass('active').addClass('btn-default');
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/gP562/4/

Comment: It wasn't quite as easy as that, unfortunately. I would like the "Yes" button to go green and not red.

Comment: @MatthewPeckham have edited to a shorter and more effective quicker method